# How do I get the output of a prime factoriser function look like as expected?

Tags: python-3.x

So I am supposed to program a prime factoriser which I did as followed:

```html
import math

n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

def primeFactoriser(n): 
    lst = []
    while n % 2 == 0: 
        #print(2) 
        n = n / 2
        lst.append(2)

    for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2): 
        while n % i == 0: 
            #print(i) 
            n = n / i  
            lst.append(i)
    if n > 2: 
        #print(int(n))
        lst.append(int(n)) 
    print(lst)

#print(lst)
print(str(n) + " = " )
print(primeFactoriser(n))
```

But the I can't figure out how to get the exact output as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, you need to *return* the list from the function: replace `print(lst)` with `return lst`. This is how you pass variables back out of a function so the caller can use the result.

Second, you need to print the list in the correct format. `str.join()` is the usual way of doing this, which means taking a string of your choice and printing it between each element of your list.

In this case, you'd want to replace

```
print(primeFactoriser(n))
```

with

```
print(' x '.join(primeFactoriser(n)))
```

---

I note that you also have two print statements. The first will likely create a newline, putting the second all on its own line. I recommend combining them all into a single print statement:

```
print(str(n), '=', ' x '.join(primeFactoriser(n)))
```

which will automatically put a space between each argument.
Or, you can keep it how you have it now, but add the `end` argument to the first print call in order to make it not print a newline:

```
print(str(n) + ' = ', end='')
```

Comment: print(str(n), '=', ' x '.join(primeFactoriser(n)))

I tried the above but keep getting a TypeError: can only join an iterable. How do I fix this?

Comment: Don't forget to make `primeFactoriser()` _return_ the `lst` you've been appending to throughout it.

Comment: FYI, I saved the returned list with name primeList. Once I returned the list, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(str(n), "=", " x ".join(primeList))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Ah, ok, so `join()` expects the iterable to be a list of strings specifically. You can fix that with a list comprehension: `" x ".join(str(i) for i in primeList)`

Comment: I did the following and now it's fixed! Thanks so much!! 

primes = primeFactoriser(n),
primeList = [str(num) for num in primes],
print(str(n), "=", " x ".join(primeList))